# Show independence of random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Let's consider $n$ discrete real valued random variables $X_1,\dots, X_n$. We have two equivalent statements

a.) "$X_1,\dots, X_n$ are independent **iff** for all $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$
$$
P(X_1=a_1,\dots, X_n=a_n)=P(X_1=a_1)\cdot P(X_2=a_2)\cdots P(X_n=a_n)"
$$

and

b.)"$X_1,\dots, X_n$ are independent **iff** for all sets $A_1,\dots,A_n\subseteq$
$$
P(X_1=A_1,\dots, X_n=A_n)=P(X_1=A_1)\cdot P(X_2=A_2)\cdots P(X_n=A_n)."
$$

(Hint: we consider $X_i:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ so that $P(X_i=A_1):=P(\omega\in\Omega\mid X_i(\omega)\in A_i)$)

---

Show that

"$X_1,\dots, X_n$ are independent **iff** for all $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$
$$
P(X_1\leq a_1,\dots, X_n\leq a_n)=P(X_1\leq a_1)\cdot P(X_2\leq a_2)\cdots P(X_n\leq a_n)"
$$

**My approach:**

The direction "$\implies$" is obvious because $\{X_i\leq a_i\}$ represents a set $A_i\subset \mathbb{R}$.

However the direction "$\Longleftarrow$" seems to a bit trickier. I started with $n=2$ and tried to manipulate the sets in an appropriate way (by inclusion/exclusion principle) but this doesn't get me anywhere:

$$\begin{align*}
&P(X_1=a_1,X_2=a_2)=1-P(X_1<a_1\cup X_2<a_2 \cup X_1>a_1 \cup X_2>a_2)\\
&=1-[P(X_1<a_1)+P(X_1>a_1)+P(X_2<a_2)+P(X_2>a_2)\\
&-P(X_1<a_1,X_2<a_2)-P(X_1<a_1,X_2>a_2)-P(X_1>a_1,X_2<a_1)-P(X_1>a_1,X_2>a_2)].
\end{align*}$$

The summands which contain more that two sets have probability $0$ as they contain expressions like $P(X_1<a_1,X_1>a_1,X_2<a_2)$ and $\{X_1<a_1,X_1>a_1\}$ represents a disjoint set.

But how does this help to produce something like $P(X_1=a_1)\cdot P(X_2=a_2)$?

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: In b) of your equivalent definition, shouldn't it be $X_j\in A_j$ instead of $X_j = A_j$?

Comment: @stange, it's a matter of notation/definition, maybe $X_i\subseteq A_i$ or $X_i\in A_i$  are a bit more common than $X_i=A_i$

Comment: It isn't really a matter of notation.  Is $X_i$ a real-valued random variable or a set-valued random variable?  If it's real valued, then it can't equal a set or be a subset of a set.  If it's set valued, it can't equal a real number.

Comment: @user6247850 I have edited my question. I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're trying to use inclusion-exclusion to find the probability of $P(X_1=a_1, \dots, X_n=a_n)$, but you don't actually have sets with a strict inequality to work with, so the inclusion-exclusion formula you get can't be used.

You get these sets because $x_i = a_i$ is equivalent to $x_i \le a_i \vee \neg x_i < a_i$. If you instead try to find the probability of $a_i < X_i \le b_i$ for all $i$, the sets you end up with in your formula will all be of the right form.

This allows you to show that the independence formula works for intervals like this:
$$P(a_1 < X_1 \le b_1 , \dots , a_n < X_n \le b_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n P(a_i < X_i \le b_i)$$

You can then use the right continuity of CDFs to find what you were looking for, by letting $a_i \to b_i$.

---

Your manipulation would have worked if you had the independence formula for all the sets of the form that ended up in your expression, e.g.
$$P(X_1<a_1,X_2>a_2) = P(X_1 < a_1)P(X_2 > a_2)$$

You could split te second part of your formula up into

$$\begin{align*}
-P(X_1<a_1)P(X_2<a_2)-P(X_1<a_1)P(X_2>a_2)-P(X_1>a_1)P(X_2<a_1)-P(X_1>a_1)P(X_2>a_2).
\end{align*}$$

Which factors as

$$-(P(X_1<a_1) + P(X_1 > a_1))(P(X_2<a_2) + P(X_2 > a_2)) = P(X1 \ne a_1)P(X_2 \ne a_2)$$

So your full formula becomes

$$\begin{align*}
&P(X_1=a_1,X_2=a_2) = 1-[P(X_1 \ne a_1)+P(X_2 \ne a_2)\\
&-P(X_1 \ne a_1)P(X_2 \ne a_2)]
\end{align*}$$

Which equals

$$1-(1-P(X_1 \ne a_1))(1-P(X_2 \ne a_2))$$

$$ = 1-P(X_1 = a_1)P(X_2 = a_2)$$

So your approach does work, when you switch to half open intervals. Though I think the manipulation might be easier if you instead used
$$\{a_1 < X_1 \le b_1 , \dots , a_n < X_n \le b_n\} = \{ X_1 \le b_1 , \dots ,  X_n \le b_n\} - \bigcup_{i=1}^n \{ X_1 \le b_1 , \dots , X_i \le a_i, \dots,  X_n \le b_n \}$$

Comment: A few remarks: 1.) It is *not* the continuity from the right side that helps but the fact that you have non-continuity i.e. a jump, if you approach $b_i$ from the left. 2.) How do you show that $$P(a_1 < X_1 \le b_1 , \dots , a_n < X_n \le b_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n P(a_i < X_i \le b_i)?$$ 3.) The set equality at the end $$\{a_1 < X_1 \le b_1 , \dots , a_n < X_n \le b_n\} = \{ X_1 \le b_1 , \dots ,  X_n \le b_n\} - \bigcup_{i=1}^n \{ X_1 \le b_1 , \dots , X_i \le a_i, \dots,  X_n \le b_n \}$$ doesn't make sense because the right side equals $\emptyset$; maybe there is a typo?